# Facebook Like Button Comments Not Working - https issue

Tags: https, facebook-like, fbml, xfbml

I'm using FBML and everything was working before, then I noticed that when you click like the comment box would not show up anymore. I checked out the dev site and saw that the way it's done now has changed.

I updated my code but it still doesn't show the comments box but the actual liking action works fine.

Here is a link: http://fez.nu/Oniir

**EDIT 2:** I'm using XFBML, I don't know if that makes a difference. I've heard that FBML is deprecated

**EDIT 3:** I browse with https on Facebook. I turned it off and the comment boxes show up on my site. So that problem is solved but how do I make it work with users that are using secure browsing on Facebook when my site is not?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I have the exact same issue. Like button no longer renders pop up box I have share button enabled and it does render the pop up box! I have also seen that code has changed and updated but behaviour stays the same with both old and new code.

Comment: Take a look at my edit #3 and try https turned off and see if it works for you. Also, no I have not found an answer for it to work with https turned on.

Comment: Well, do you host your XFBML via https? And by the way, your link is outdated.

Comment: @EdwindeKoning, I fixed the link. I'm pulling the code for the Like Button from [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). Are you telling me that my website has to have an SSL cert and be https to use the button fully? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Why not? If one part of the page is served over http, while another is served over https, it seems to me you are getting 'mixed content'. Which leads to all sorts of problems. Could you perhaps show me the code of your like button? (The link still doesn't work)

Comment: @EdwindeKoning I understand the mixed part but it used to work and I was browsing as secure when it was working. How does the Send functionality of the button pop-up and work even if the comment box doesn't? Here is the code I use and the link works (I promise) now. `<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-layout="box_count" data-width="70" data-show-faces="false"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an HTML inline frame.

```
<iframe src="https://mytab.example.com/tabs/"></iframe>
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587021/facebook-like-button-breaks-https-ssl) has produced an accepted solution to what appears to be your problem.

**Abstract**

> You can avoid SSL warnings for domains that support SSL by not being
>   specific about the transport protocol. e.g. instead of including
>   http:// or https:// use //

```
<!-- Instead of this: --> 
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?params"></iframe>

<!-- Do this: -->
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?params"></iframe>
```

**Security considerations**

Please note that there are some security considerations to this approach. I recommend you read the below articles and questions.

- [Are there security issues with embedding an https iframe on an http page](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/894/are-there-security-issues-with-embedding-an-https-iframe-on-an-http-page) (SE question)
- [HTTP and HTTPS iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144986/http-https-iframe) (SO question)
- [Other considerations when serving mixed (http/https) content](http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/facebook-secure-browsing-https-iframe-tabs-mixed-content-warnings/) (external site)

---

**Edit 1**

In the [FAQ for the Like Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), it's stated that it will need 400 pixels in width to give the user the option to add a comment. If you don't have 400 pixels available, I think you would have to sacrifice the option to post a comment, or use a popup-window instead.

Comment: I'm not using iframes currently for two reasons. 1) When I first implemented the like button comments only worked with XFBML. Now I see that it works with iframes but that leads to 2) I don't have 400px in width to give the button.

Comment: Like I said when I first implemented the button I did it with XFBML and the comments worked. I guess now I'm trying to find out when this changed and why. I've seen that FBML is deprecated, does that mean XFBML is deprecated also? If that is the case then I will make the iframe work, I'm developing another theme for the site so we can live without the comments for now.

Answer (score 0):

This problem started last night.

I thought it was my code at first but a quick rollback to code I KNOW (QA Tested) worked manifested the issue.

I went to the source itself, Facebook's OWN Like button generation tool and THEY have the same problem.

Then I picked BOTH a random CNN & Yahoo news article and that is what you call a trifecta. All 3 sites could not properly render the comments UI elements for the like button.

If it walks, quacks and moves its head like a duck... WTF? :))

Comment: This link should make it clear it is a facebook coding issue: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/