# Like button does not show on https pages

Tags: https, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

Today our facebook like button was not showing at all after some reasearch I figured out I had to add the http: to it.  It is now working for all http page but not any https page.  Please help.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587021/facebook-like-button-breaks-https-ssl